# x many for loops - how to do that?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

Basically I have a problem, which requires me to do x many for loops (for each number in a loop, x is different).

Maybe there's another way of doing this task, which I haven't figured out.

Here's what I need to do. I have these functions:

```
connections = {}

def arrow(x, y):
    if x not in connections.keys():
        connections[x] = [y]
    else:
        connections[x].append(y)

def draw(x):
    if 2 * x <= n:
        arrow(x, 2 * x)
        draw(2 * x)

    if (2 * x) + 1 <= n:
        arrow(x, (2 * x) + 1)
        draw((2 * x) + 1)
```

For each key in connections I draw a line (arrow) to both values.

Task: I have a list of 1000 pairs [x, y] where y > x. And I need to figure out whether I can get from x to y only going downwards (with the flow of the arrow) using one or more arrows.

My approach was to iterate through every possible combination for example: connections[1] = [2, 3] so I "choose" 2 then 4 and so on. if the current position (number) is too big I try another combination for example 2 then 5 or 3 then 6. The problem is I don't know how many for loops I need to use for different [x, y] pairs. How do I do that?

Comment: for n = 5, draw(1) looks like this: 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5.

Comment: If you want to be able to traverse a network, you should keep it as a network of nodes and not points. You don't have information loss the way you have it, but you make it that much harder.

Comment: also, if that's important, for my task I use n = 100_00 and draw(1)

Comment: @Shmack thanks for the comment, I am really new to the topic of CP, could you tell me what should I google etc?

Comment: A personal preference, instead of `arrow(x, 2*x)`, you can do in one line `connections.setdefault(x, []).append(2*x)` using [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Comment: You don't need `for`-loops. You used recursion for `draw`; you can use recursion for your task too. Imagine a function which is almost exactly like `draw`, but at each step it tests whether `x == y`.

Comment: @Stef why recompute the whole thing, when you could save it as a network and traverse it to see if you could reach it? Presumably, you already have to draw it to show the connections or pass it to a function to draw a graph or something.

Comment: @Shmack Do you actually have a question for me or was that rhetorical?

Comment: Actual question.